# Error while XML parsing with JDOM - Content not allowed in prolog

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jdom

I get this error while parsing an xml file using JDOM.
What is happening is, I receive a stream of data which is an xml combined with a pdf as an attachment within it. So when I try to create a document of it, this error is thrown.
I tried to print this stream and on the console I get the following, It is with lot of junk chars(the pdf contents) but in Wordpad it looks like -

```
------=_Part_2_23286828.1296553488632
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8

<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
....
....
....
    <Attachment>
        <URI>Filename.pdf</URI>
    </Attachment>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
------=_Part_2_23286828.1296553488632
Content-Type: application/pdf; name="Filename.pdf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: </Attachment[1]/URI[1]>
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Filename.pdf"

%PDF-1.4
%âãÏÓ
4 0 obj <</Type/XObject/ColorSpace/DeviceRGB/Subtype/Image/BitsPerComponent 8/Width 579/Length 52722/Height 480/Filter/DCTDecode>>stream
ÿØÿà
```

Please note that the xml between `<SOAP-ENV:Envelope>` and `</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>` is well-formed.
How could I go about and create a JDOM document out of it? I guess, by removing the content before and after the xml start/end tags but how in a clean way?
I read that BOMInputStream from Apache IO Commons is helpful but I believe it is in version 2.* and I am using version 1.3.1

I hope this explains my problem, if not pls let me know.
Thank you.

`UPDATE`
At first I didnt realize it would be this cumbersome.
Actually, I am making a call from one servlet to another(doPost) using HttpURLConnection. The return is in the form of this stream.
Now, I am also trying to explore if in any way I can extract the xml part using some of the methods provided by Http/URLConnection.
Appreciate if anyone could shed some more light on this.

Answer (score 1):

This message conforms to the SOAP with Attachment specification (http://www.w3.org/TR/SOAP-attachments).  In java the way to parse these messages is to use an implementation of the SAAJ (Soap with Attachments API for Java: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbhf.html.) There are a couple of different implementations of SAAJ out there.  My personal favorite is the Spring-WS implementation another option is Apache Axiom.

My suggestion to you would be use either Spring-WS or Apache Axis to process this message rather than trying to do it manually from an input stream. Are you trying to do this on the server side or on the client side?